# Specifying the decimal precision for a call to std::copy

Tags: c++, vector, fstream, precision, ofstream

I have the following function that saves a vector to a CSV file:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

bool save_vector(vector<double>* pdata, size_t length,
                 const string& file_path)
{
  ofstream os(file_path.c_str(), ios::binary | ios::out);
  if (!os.is_open())
    {
      cout << "Failure!" << endl;
      return false;
    }
  copy(pdata->begin(), pdata->end(), ostream_iterator<double>(os, ","));
  os.close();
  return true;
}
```

In the resulting CSV file, the numbers in `pdata` are saved with variable precision, and none are saved with the precision I want (10 decimal places).

I know about the function `std::setprecision`.  However, this function, according to the [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/),

> should only be used as a stream manipulator.

(I'm actually not sure I'm interpreting "stream manipulator" correctly; I'm assuming this means I can't use it in my function as currently written.)

Is there a way for me to specify the decimal precision using the `copy` function?  If not, how should I get rid of `copy` so that I can use `setprecision` in the function above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call

```
os.precision(10);
```

before the copy.

Comment: this seems to specify the number of non-zero digits that are written.  so, in my case, to get 10 digits after the decimal place, i want `os.precision(11)`.